# knife client list not showing my workstation

Tags: chef-infra

Following is my knife.rb config and respected files are present at the mentioned location

```
# See http://docs.chef.io/config_rb_knife.html for more information on knife configuration options

current_dir = File.dirname(__FILE__)
log_level                :info
log_location             STDOUT
node_name                "anshulp25"
client_key               "#{current_dir}/anshulp25.pem"
validation_client_name   "deathstartatooine-validator"
validation_key           "#{current_dir}/deathstartatooine-validator.pem"
chef_server_url          "https://api.chef.io/organizations/deathstartatooine"
cookbook_path            ["#{current_dir}/../cookbooks"]
```

But when I do

```
knife client list
```

I get the following output

```
$ knife client list
deathstartatooine-validator
```

Shouldn't the `anshulp25` entry be listed ?

Following is chef details

```
$ chef --version
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.10.0
chef-client version: 12.5.1
berks version: 4.0.1
kitchen version: 1.4.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure, how to further describe it - but you're workstation connects as [user](https://docs.chef.io/knife_user.html).

You can use `knife user list` to show all users.

That changed with some Chef 11 version, as before both workstations and nodes were just clients.